# Compaq Presario B1900 can't detect USB devices

Tags: 13.04, usb, lubuntu

I've just discovered that none of my USB ports appear to be functioning correctly on my Lubuntu install. lsusb shows I have the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

So far the only thing I appear to have gotten to detect and work correctly is a usb mouse (below) and my phone will charge (but not be detected) when plugged in.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4d64 Primax Electronics, Ltd
```

Three USB memory sticks I have to hand and a printer I was trying to install don't appear to be detected at all.

Does anyone have any pointers I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this:

- Install dconf-editor

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
  ```
- When installed open it using following command and follow mentioned path:

  ```
  dconf-editor
  ```
- Path: org->gnome->desktop->media-handling and check `automount` and `automount-open`
- Sometime it detects but doesn't mount, so execute following command and see what happens:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

  `sudo mount` displays all the media that is mounted in your system..
- If it does not work then try to open your system in another shell like `gnome-classic` or `gnome-class(no effects)` from login screen and check what happens.

Hope it somewhat helps you!!

<sub>[Source : help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB)</sub>